# Dropboxで同期された1つのXcodeプロジェクトを2台のMacで同時に開いたまま開発しても問題ありませんか。

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

2台のMac(Mac AとMac Bとします)の間で、DropboxでXcodeのプロジェクトを同期しています。
このプロジェクト(`.xcodeproj`または`.xcworkspace`)をそれぞれのMacで同時に開き、交互に編集を行っても問題はありませんか。
開発は1人で行うため、1つのファイルを同時に編集してコンフリクトが発生することはありません。

現在は、Mac Aで開発 → Mac AでXcodeを閉じる → Mac Bで開発 → Mac BでXcodeを閉じる → Mac Aで開発 → ……のように、同時にプロジェクトを開かないようにしていますが、面倒に感じています。
これを、わざわざXcodeを閉じなくても大丈夫かどうか、という質問です。

適当なプロジェクトを作って同時に開き、交互にファイルの編集や追加をしてみたところ、問題なく開発できていますが、間違いなく大丈夫という確信は持てなかったので質問させていただきました。
実際に同じようなことをされている方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

これは自分も試したことがあるのですが、自分の場合はちょいちょい Xcode が落ちました。
Mac AとMac Bではリンク先のパスが異なるためかなーと思っていたのですが、質問者様の環境では問題なく開発できているようなら大丈夫なんじゃないでしょうか！
おっしゃるとおり、間違いなく大丈夫という保証はありませんので、しばらく続けてみて、プロジェクトが壊れるようなことがあればやめたほうが良いと思います。